# Update using subquery sets same value for all records

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to calculate the weight of each record based on the value of a column (`updated_at`). When I run the following query:

```
UPDATE buyers
SET weight = RankedRecords.rank / (RankedRecords.count + 1.0)
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY board_list_id ORDER BY 'updated_at' ASC
      ) AS rank,
    COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY board_list_id) AS count
  FROM buyers
) RankedRecords
WHERE buyers.id = RankedRecords.id
```

All records with the same `board_list_id` get their `weight` updated to the same value. While I expect all `weight` values to be different and depend on rank.
Running just the subquery produces correct results (each record has different rank). But updating doesn't work as expected.
What should I change?

Comment: Can you post the structure of `buyers` (only the relevant columns) and some sample data?

Comment: Remove quotes in `'updated_at'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very subtle mistake in your query. Try this instead:

```
UPDATE 
    buyers
SET 
    weight = RankedRecords.rank / (RankedRecords.count + 1.0)
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        id,
        rank()    OVER (PARTITION BY board_list_id ORDER BY updated_at ASC) AS rank,
        count(id) OVER (PARTITION BY board_list_id) AS count
    FROM buyers
) RankedRecords
WHERE 
    buyers.id = RankedRecords.id ;
```

Your litle mistake: `ORDER BY 'updated_at'` is just `ORDER BY 'constant-text'`. If you want to refer to the column, you either use `"updated_at"` (with *double* quotes) or `updated_at` (without them, because the name of your column is just ASCII lowercase chars).

Tried with:

```
CREATE TABLE buyers
(
    id integer not null primary key,
    board_list_id integer not null,
    updated_at timestamp not null default now(),
    weight double precision
) ;
INSERT INTO buyers (id, board_list_id, updated_at) 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, '2017-01-09'),
    (2, 1, '2017-01-10'),
    (3, 1, '2017-01-11'),
    (4, 1, '2017-01-12'),
    (5, 2, '2017-01-09'),
    (6, 2, '2017-01-10'),
    (7, 2, '2017-01-11'),
    (8, 1, '2017-01-12') ;
```

The result of the previous UPDATE (with a RETURNING * clause) would be:

```
|----+---------------+---------------------+--------+----+------+-------|
| id | board_list_id |     updated_at      | weight | id | rank | count |
|----+---------------+---------------------+--------+----+------+-------|
| 1  |       1       | 2017-01-09 00:00:00 | 0.1667 | 1  |  1   |   5   |
|----+---------------+---------------------+--------+----+------+-------|
| 2  |       1       | 2017-01-10 00:00:00 | 0.3333 | 2  |  2   |   5   |
|----+---------------+---------------------+--------+----+------+-------|
| 3  |       1       | 2017-01-11 00:00:00 | 0.5    | 3  |  3   |   5   |
|----+---------------+---------------------+--------+----+------+-------|
| 8  |       1       | 2017-01-12 00:00:00 | 0.6667 | 8  |  4   |   5   |
|----+---------------+---------------------+--------+----+------+-------|
| 4  |       1       | 2017-01-12 00:00:00 | 0.6667 | 4  |  4   |   5   |
|----+---------------+---------------------+--------+----+------+-------|
| 5  |       2       | 2017-01-09 00:00:00 | 0.25   | 5  |  1   |   3   |
|----+---------------+---------------------+--------+----+------+-------|
| 6  |       2       | 2017-01-10 00:00:00 | 0.5    | 6  |  2   |   3   |
|----+---------------+---------------------+--------+----+------+-------|
| 7  |       2       | 2017-01-11 00:00:00 | 0.75   | 7  |  3   |   3   |
|----+---------------+---------------------+--------+----+------+-------|
```